# Vite, React, and react-lazy: Relative image paths not working for both development and build phases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, directory, vite

I'm working on a React project using Vite as the build tool, and I'm trying to implement lazy loading of images using the react-lazy-load-image-component library. I'm facing issues with relative image paths during both development and build phases.

Here's the structure of my project:

```
my-project/
|-- public/
|-- src/
|   |-- assets/
|       |-- images/
|           |-- projects/
|               |-- presto_store.jpg
|               |-- presto_store-compressed.jpg
|   |-- components/
|       |-- ProjectSection/
|            |-- ProjectSection.jsx
|            |-- ProjectCard.jsx
|       |-- AboutMeSection.jsx
|-- index.html
|-- package.json
|-- vite.config.js
```

In the **AboutMeSection.jsx** file, I import the images and use the imported objects as the src and placeholderSrc props for the LazyLoadImage component, and it works perfectly during both development and build phases:

```
import ProfilePic from "../assets/images/Img_square1.jpg";
import BlurredProfilePic from "../assets/images/Img_square1-compressed.jpg";

<LazyLoadImage
  className="profile-pic"
  src={ProfilePic}
  alt="Immagine Profilo"
  effect="blur"
  placeholderSrc={BlurredProfilePic}
/>
```

However, in the **ProjectCard.jsx** component, I need to use relative image paths as props to keep the component agnostic to the actual image paths:

```
const ProjectCard = ({
  // ... other props
  imgPath,
  placeholderPath,
}) => {
  // ... other code

  return (
    // ... other code
    <LazyLoadImage
      className="project-img"
      src={imgPath}
      alt={title}
      placeholderSrc={placeholderPath}
      effect="opacity"
    />
    // ... other code
  );
};

export default React.memo(ProjectCard);
```

When I use the component like this inside **ProjectSection.jsx** (A section where ProjectCards are create and displayed dynamically), like this:

```
<ProjectCard
  imgPath="/assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg"
  placeholderPath="/assets/images/projects/presto_store-compressed.jpg"
  // ... other props
/>
```

or even:

- "assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg"
- "./assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg"
- "../assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg"
- "../../assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg"

The images are not displayed both in development and build. If I use paths starting with "src/", it works only in the development environment but not in the build.

I need a solution that allows me to use relative image paths with Vite, React, and the react-lazy-load-image-component library so that the images are displayed correctly in both development and build phases, thanks a lot.
**PS:**
When I say not displaying I mean:*"http://localhost:5173/assets/images/projects/presto_store.jpg 404 (Not Found)"* in development mode.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

Also, chat GPT suggested me some weird stuff like importing the path library and doing like so, but it doesn't work. And I can't belive it has to be this hard, im surely missing out something simple:

```
const resolvedImgPath = path.resolve(import.meta.env.BASE_URL, imgPath);
  const resolvedPlaceholderPath = path.resolve(import.meta.env.BASE_URL, placeholderPath);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the asset folder into public.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory